# How to Query Drafts by Message ID?

Tags: gmail-api

We have a use case where we have the message ID of a draft and want to get the immutable draft ID. Currently the only way to do this is to list all the drafts and iterate through them until we find a matching message id.

Would it be possible to add functionality to query the drafts by message ID? Alternatively, if the draft ID could be included with a Get message by ID call then that could work to.

Comment: You can't retrieve a draft through message id.  All the draft methods needs draft id and all messages methods needs just message id. But if you give message id of the draft in messages.get, you can retrieve the draft of that message.

Comment: If I give the message Id to messages.get then I get a Message object back. This object does not have the draft id as far as I can tell. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: Ya you don't see the draft id, but you can see the draft body.

Comment: need the draft id so i can send the thing.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible now and seems like an odd edge case.  What's the downside of iterating all drafts.list?  I imagine 99% there's < 50 drafts so it should be relatively cheap/efficient.

If there are a lot of drafts or some other reason you don't want to look at all of the drafts the best workaround I'd say is:

messages.get(msgid_of_draft) to get the rfc822 "Message-Id" header

drafts.list(q="rfc822msgid:") to get a draft id, this is an indexed search should be fast and only return one thing

drafts.get(draft_id)

Comment: listDrafts doesn't actually have a q parameter, unless that's an undocumented feature

Comment: It does have now.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/list

Comment: fwfiw messages.get(msgid_of_draft).getHeader('Message-Id') always returns an empty string for me